# problem in letter's language

Tags: c#, visual-studio, character-encoding

I have a problem
after i setup windows 7 all old projects in c# vs 2005, the letters that written in arabic changed to a strange language
and i changed the language's settings in control panel to arabic then the new projects passed but the old projects have the same problem

Comment: "Strange language" is a very vague desciption. Could you provide an example of your "strange language" - copy/paste or a screenshot? I suspect it's just not detecting the character set correctly, but unless I can see what you are seeing, it's only a qualified guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this small program and your problem will be solved http://www.zshare.net/download/73795804952ece65/

Comment: sorry but I am not the programmer of this program..but I know that it is very helpful in your problem

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 uses unicode strings whereas your previous projects were using ASCII strings. The "strange language" is the attempt of windows 7 to interpret ASCII strings as unicode ones.
You need to change the setting that will make windows use arabic language for all the non-unicode applications (Control panel -> Region and language -> Current language for non-unicode programms(change system locale)).

Comment: all projects became in right language exept one that i have opened when the unicode in forign language
what i have to do???